# User-defined result on Ansys using ACT: how to compute volume of last substep only?

Tags: python, ironpython, volume, ansys

I use an ACT defined result code that compute the volume of a surface body post deformation.
The volume is calculated using a convex hull function (in "scipy_Fun.py").
This code works well for simulations with 1 time-step. However when I simulate the deformation in 10 substeps, the code is applied to every single one of them and it's very time consuming.
Is there a way to indicate in the script that, only the volume at the last step has to be computed?

"main" script:

```
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit")
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit.Base")
import os
import subprocess
import units
from Ansys.UI.Toolkit import *

   def __init__(context):
        ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("initiating Scipy manipulate...")
    pass

   def CreateCustomPost(analysis):
        ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("clicked on CustomPost button")
     
   result=analysis.CreateResultObject("CustomPost")


   def Manipulate(result,stepInfo,collector):
        step=stepInfo.Set
        analysis=result.Analysis
        reader=analysis.GetResultsData()
        reader.CurrentResultSet=step
        Disp=reader.GetResult("U")
        #DispUx=Disp.GetNodeValues(66)[0]
        mesh=analysis.MeshData

WorkingdirName=analysis.WorkingDir #what is the working directory of the project 
InstallDir=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir
#OneUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtAPI.DataModel.AnalysisList[0].WorkingDir,'..')
#TwoUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(OneUp,'..')
#ThreeUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(TwoUp,'..')
UserFiles=System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtAPI.DataModel.AnalysisList[0].WorkingDir)#solver file directory and 3 steps back

AnsResfilename=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Input.csv" #gives name to the input and output files
ManResfilename=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Output.csv"

ipfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,AnsResfilename) #create the path to the new files supposed to be in the user_files folder
opfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,ManResfilename)

f1=open(ipfile,"w") #open file in user directory


global nodeResults
import units

analysis = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.Analyses[0]
mesh = analysis.MeshData
# Get nodes 
allNodes = mesh.Nodes
# get the result data
reader = analysis.GetResultsData()
# get the deformation result
myDeformation = reader.GetResult("U")
nodeResultsTemp = []
result_unit = myDeformation.GetComponentInfo("X").Unit
for node in allNodes:
#get node deformation and convert values in meter
    deformationNode1 = myDeformation.GetNodeValues(node.Id)
    deformationNode1[0] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[0],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    deformationNode1[1] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[1],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    deformationNode1[2] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[2],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    #add node coordinates (in meter) to the displacement
    mesh_unit = mesh.Unit
    node1 = mesh.NodeById(node.Id)
    node1CoorX = units.ConvertUnit(node1.X,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")   
    node1CoorY = units.ConvertUnit(node1.Y,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")   
    node1CoorZ = units.ConvertUnit(node1.Z,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")     
    deformationNode1[0] = deformationNode1[0]+node1CoorX
    deformationNode1[1] = deformationNode1[1]+node1CoorY
    deformationNode1[2] = deformationNode1[2]+node1CoorZ
    nodeResultsTemp.append([deformationNode1[0],deformationNode1[1],deformationNode1[2]])
    f1.write(str(node.Id)+","+str(deformationNode1[0])+","+str(deformationNode1[1])+","+str(deformationNode1[2])+"\n")
nodeResults = nodeResultsTemp

#nodeIds=collector.Ids
#ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(str(nodeIds))
#for nId in nodeIds:
#f1.write(str(nodeResults)) #write node Id and displacement Ux
f1.close()

ScaleFactor =result.Properties["DispFactor"].Value  #take the value entered manually
result.Properties["InputFileName"].Value=AnsResfilename # fill the fields in mechanical
result.Properties["OutputFileName"].Value=ManResfilename

callCpython(ScaleFactor,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile) #call cpython

import csv #after the Cpython function 
resfile=opfile
reader=csv.reader(open(resfile,'rb'),quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) #read the node number and the scaled displ 

NodeNos=next(reader)
ICVs=next(reader)
#ScaledUxs=next(reader)
a=int(NodeNos[1])
b=ICVs[1]
ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(a.GetType().ToString())
ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(b.GetType().ToString())
userUnit=ExtAPI.DataModel.CurrentUnitFromQuantityName("Length")
DispFactor=units.ConvertUnit(1,userUnit,"mm")

for id in collector.Ids:
    collector.SetValues(int(NodeNos[NodeNos.index(id)]), {ICVs[NodeNos.index(id)]*DispFactor}) #plot results
  
ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("ICV read")

return True


def callCpython(ScaleFactor,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile,input=None):
    InstallDir=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir
    python39=r"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
    PyinputFile=os.path.join(InstallDir,"A_ScipyFun.py")

ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(str(ScaleFactor))

process=subprocess.Popen([python39,PyinputFile,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile,str(ScaleFactor)]) #with supprocess module we can open any .exe program along with some arguments
process.wait() #we want to open Python.exe + input file that this .exe is supposed to use (to do that we supply another python file that will be executed in Cpython)

#subprocess.call([python39,PyinputFile,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile])
#all elements in this list must be a string
#str = convert float into string
return True
```

xml file:

```
<extension version="11" minorversion="0" name="ACTResults">

  <author>Ansys Inc.</author>
  <description>ACTResults</description>
  <guid shortid="ACTResults">*****</guid>
  <script src="main.py" />
  <script src="A_ScipyFun.py"/>
   <interface context="Mechanical">
  <images>images</images>
 <toolbar name="ACTResults" caption="ACTResults">
   <entry name="CustomPost" icon="hand">
     <callbacks>
       <onclick>CreateCustomPost</onclick>
     </callbacks>
   </entry>
 </toolbar>
</interface>

 <simdata context="Mechanical">
    <result name="CustomPost" version="11" caption="CustomPost" 
    icon="hand" location="node" type="scalar" timehistory= 
     "true">
        <callbacks>
         <evaluate>Manipulate</evaluate>
        </callbacks>
      <property name="Geometry" caption="Geometry" 
      control="scoping"></property>
      <property name="DispFactor" caption="DispFactor" 
      control="float" default = "5.0"></property>
      <property name="InputFileName" caption="Input csv File 
      Name" 
      control="text" default="auto" readonly="true"></property>
      <property name="OutputFileName" caption="Output csv File 
      Name" 
      control="text" default="auto" readonly="true"></property>
   
  </result>
</simdata>
</extension>
```

volume computation code:

```
import sys
import os

def ScipyRW(UserFiles,inputfile,outputfile,SF):
#Sample code for testing Scipy library from IronPython(ACT)
import scipy as sp 
import numpy as np
import time
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scaleFactor=float(SF) #reconvert into float

print(UserFiles)
print(inputfile)
print(outputfile)
print(scaleFactor)

fn=open(inputfile,'r')
line=fn.readline()


Col_1=[]
Col_2=[]
Col_3=[]
Col_4=[]
#replaced while with for-loop
  for line in open(inputfile):
      v = line.split(',')
      Col_1.append(float((v[0]))) #reading column 1
      Col_2.append(float((v[1]))) #reading column 2
      Col_3.append(float((v[2]))) #reading column 3
      Col_4.append(float((v[3]))) #reading column 4

from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

#Replaced append with direct assignment
NodeNo=Col_1
#Added a matrix transpose and fixed brackets
Matrix=np.array([Col_2,Col_3,Col_4]).T

myhull = ConvexHull(Matrix)
vol= myhull.volume
ar = myhull.area
print(vol)
print(ar)
myICV = vol-(ar*scaleFactor)

print(myICV/1000)

#we should get one number as output and it has to be a paramater
#for that, I need to add a line to the xml file : <property name="ICV_approx" caption="ICV_approx" control="float" unit = volume readonly = "true" isparameter="true"></property>

print("csv file read")

import numpy as np
#NodeNo=np.array(Col_1)
ICV=np.full_like(NodeNo,myICV)
np.savetxt(outputfile,(NodeNo,ICV),delimiter=',',fmt='%f')  #save output into txt file --> opfile

print ("Input csv file processed by numpy and written out")

 ScipyRW(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4]) #call 
 the function inside Cpython throught this
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: How are you excecuting this code snippet?

Comment: I've created an extension so I add the results in the solution tab and it's executed when I run the simulation (I've set it up this way because I will later need to perform a DoE). I've just tried to insert the line you suggested but the volume is still computed for every time steps

Comment: the resulting volume remains the same for each time step

Comment: Could you please also post the code from the accompanying .xml file?

Comment: done. I've also added the second script which is called by the main just in case

Comment: I changed my answer. Could you test this?

Comment: the same thing happens, the python terminal pop up several times and it still takes a relatively long time to get to finalise the simulation after that (I set up 2 time steps for the tests)

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit puzzled. At the moment I just can think of one other thing. Changed the answer again.

Comment: Same thing. Thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As meshWorker suggested in one of his answers/edits, switching 'timehistory' to 'false' should be the solution.

```
<simdata context="Mechanical">
<result name="CustomPost" version="11" caption="CustomPost" 
icon="hand" location="node" type="scalar" timehistory="false">
```

I have tried in a dummy model, with your scripts but instead of calling A_ScipyFun.py for your calculations just asking to write some data of the Log window. When 'timehistory' is 'true', it writes a message for every step, when I switch it to 'false' (considering that the custom result object is set to 'By' -> 'Time' and 'DisplayTime' -> 'Last'), just write the message once.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the duplicate calls from the `Manipulate()` function:

```
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit")
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit.Base")
import os
import subprocess
import units
from Ansys.UI.Toolkit import *

def __init__(context):
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("initiating Scipy manipulate...")
pass

def CreateCustomPost(analysis):
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("clicked on CustomPost button")
 
result=analysis.CreateResultObject("CustomPost")


def Manipulate(result,stepInfo,collector):
    analysis = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.Analyses[0]
    reader=analysis.GetResultsData()
    reader.CurrentResultSet=reader.ResultSetCount
    Disp=reader.GetResult("U")
    #DispUx=Disp.GetNodeValues(66)[0]
    mesh=analysis.MeshData

WorkingdirName=analysis.WorkingDir #what is the working directory of the project 
InstallDir=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir
#OneUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtAPI.DataModel.AnalysisList[0].WorkingDir,'..')
#TwoUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(OneUp,'..')
#ThreeUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(TwoUp,'..')
UserFiles=System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtAPI.DataModel.AnalysisList[0].WorkingDir)#solver file directory and 3 steps back

AnsResfilename=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Input.csv" #gives name to the input and output files
ManResfilename=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Output.csv"

ipfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,AnsResfilename) #create the path to the new files supposed to be in the user_files folder
opfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,ManResfilename)

f1=open(ipfile,"w") #open file in user directory

global nodeResults
import units

# Get nodes 
allNodes = mesh.Nodes

# get the deformation result
myDeformation = reader.GetResult("U")
nodeResultsTemp = []
result_unit = myDeformation.GetComponentInfo("X").Unit
for node in allNodes:
#get node deformation and convert values in meter
    deformationNode1 = myDeformation.GetNodeValues(node.Id)
    deformationNode1[0] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[0],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    deformationNode1[1] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[1],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    deformationNode1[2] = units.ConvertUnit(deformationNode1[2],result_unit,"mm","Length")
    #add node coordinates (in meter) to the displacement
    mesh_unit = mesh.Unit
    node1 = mesh.NodeById(node.Id)
    node1CoorX = units.ConvertUnit(node1.X,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")   
    node1CoorY = units.ConvertUnit(node1.Y,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")   
    node1CoorZ = units.ConvertUnit(node1.Z,mesh_unit,"mm","Length")     
    deformationNode1[0] = deformationNode1[0]+node1CoorX
    deformationNode1[1] = deformationNode1[1]+node1CoorY
    deformationNode1[2] = deformationNode1[2]+node1CoorZ
    nodeResultsTemp.append([deformationNode1[0],deformationNode1[1],deformationNode1[2]])
    f1.write(str(node.Id)+","+str(deformationNode1[0])+","+str(deformationNode1[1])+","+str(deformationNode1[2])+"\n")
nodeResults = nodeResultsTemp
```

Comment: I think it is, because without the user defined result, I get the deformation results within 1 min. As soon as I "unsuppress" my code, I  can see the python terminal pop up at every time steps (for one time step, the CPU time with the code is already a few minutes, it probably needs to be optimized but I'm not very familiar with this language)